# MVC : JQuery go to action with first row id Only

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

here is table contain more row,each row has url : /Unit/Dept/Id
when ckick for any row button edit_dept go to the action with the first row parameter , each row come like /Unit/Dept/1

```
<table id="tbUnits" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td> Name</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="edit_dept" class="btn-bootstrap-dialog edit_dept"> Edit</button>
                <div class="modal fade" id="Dept2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal-label" aria-hidden="true" data-url='@Url.Action("Dept", "Unit", new { Id = item.Id }, null)'></div>
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

here is JQuery
i need to send the specific row parameter (Id) to action

```
@section scripts
{
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $("#tbUnits").DataTable();



            $('.edit_dept').click(function () {
                var url = $('#Dept2').data('url');
                alert(url);
                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $('#Dept2').html(data);

                    $('#Dept2').modal('show');
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use id selector like`$('#Dept2')` it will always going to select first element it find in DOM with Dept2 id.

But you can select your expected element with selecting parent and then using find to select element inside that particular element. You have to use `$(this).closest('td').find('#Dept2')` for that.

Try with.

`var url = $(this).closest('td').find('#Dept2').data('url');`

Comment: To downvoter, it will be really helpful if you mention what’s wrong with the answer.